Unable to access local disk partition
I am unable to access local disk partitions from Kubuntu.
Error message "An error occurred while accessing local disks.
The system responds:
The request operation has failed: Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at media/abhisek//local disks: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing code page or helper program or other error"
Everything was working fine until this evening but then I don't know what happened, I can't access any local disk except the Kubuntu disk.
Windows Fast Boot is turned off, ntfs-3g is installed.
All methods are tried including format and fresh Kubuntu installation but again it's failed to mount disks.
Same problem with live boot usb.

Do $ sudo fdisk -l (from the bash prompt / Terminal) and include the output in your positing, mark the text and make it be a code block; i.e. click { }

use the disk utility, select the partition, select repair the filesystem, and remount the partition.
